# warning: iPad: Icon-72.png: icon dimensions (0 x 0)

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode, ipad

I got this problem: "warning: iPad: Icon-72.png: icon dimensions (0 x 0) don't meet the size requirements.  The icon file must be 72x72 pixels, in .png format (-19014)" when build for archive the iPad only app.
Have checked, my icon is 72x72 pixels. Also checked on info.plist file, the key CFBundleIconFiles already there. Before this have no problem to submit the app. After rejected by app review I want to resubmit (no changes has been made on my Xcode project) but the error appear. Does it because of I've upgraded to Mac OSX Lion 10.7.3? (I just update to Mac OSX Lion 10.7.3 before resubmit the app).

Wonder why does the warning says "icon dimensions (0 x 0)".

Please help me. Thanks.

Comment: check the case of the name in plist it could be either icon-72 instead of Icon-72

Comment: @InderKumarRathore checked, the case is same as the file name with capital letter I, Icon-72.png

Comment: I have the same problem. I tried verifying a new Build of our app, but it fails with _iPhone/iPod Touch: iPhoneAppIcon.png icon dimensions (0x0) don't meet the size requirements. The icon file must be 57x57 pixels, in .png format_. I updated to 10.7.3 as well this morning. To be sure I tried to verify an older version of the build which verified fine a couple of days ago and I get the same error. Must be an issue with 10.7.3

Comment: I'm seeing this issue with 10.7.3, and I'm running the Xcode 4.2.1.  Does anyone know if Xcode 4.3 Developer Preview 3 shows this issue?

Comment: Using 10.6.8 (Snow Leopard), same problem

Answer (score 70, accepted):

I installed Application Loader and the problem with Xcode got solved. Found the solution on Apple Developer forums [here](https://devforums.apple.com/message/612098)

Comment: here is the download link to the Application loader https://itunesconnect.apple.com/apploader/ApplicationLoader_2.5.1.dmg
Just to be clear, I see many comments about switching compression to NO for PNG photo files in the project settings, this is not a good idea. Don't turn off compression for PNG files.

Comment: Also note: you do not need to actually use the Application Loader to upload your build. Simply installing it and then restarting XCode and rebuilding your app works.

Comment: An install of Application Loader did the trick for me too! Thanks @AndreasZ!

Comment: Handy blog post about it here too: http://blog.manbolo.com/2012/02/02/macosx-10.7.3-update-breaks-ios-app-validation  ...but yes just installing 'Application Loader' fixes it. No need to use it, but probably best to quit xCode while you're installing. When you restart and rebuild, the warning's gone!

Answer (score 22):

I found a solution thanks to a forum post on the [official developer forums](https://devforums.apple.com/message/599383#599383).

1. click on your project in the tree view
2. choose the project
3. go to *Build Settings*
4. be sure to select *All*
5. search for PNG and set the value to **NO**

[image]

Seems to be a bug in Lion 10.7.3

Comment: You really don't want to turn off PNG compression. I'd recommend downloading the new Application Loader instead, as suggested by others.

Comment: Ya, download the new Application Loader is the solution. Thanks @HiltonCampbell :)

Comment: More of a quick and dirty workaround… this will increase the size of the app!

Comment: At that moment it was the only known solution to get the app up in the app store. The new version of the Application Loader was not available yet.

Comment: This didn't solve this issue and I read it is not a recommended solution

Answer (score 9):

Another solution, without installing Application Loader, is to set the File Type of all your icon files to "Icon" instead of PNG Image. This is done by selecting the Icon in Xcode and going to the File inspector panel.

Comment: This worked for me and was simpler than downloading/installing Application Loader.  You can easily find the icon files by typing "icon" in the bottom search filter of the project navigator.

Comment: This worked for me, and seems much better than the current top solution. It does not require modifying the assets, losing the benefits of compression, or installing new software.

Comment: It says now unable to verify icon dimensions now . . .

Answer (score 6):

Download new `Application Loader` and upload your app with it.

Comment: This worked for me. Turning off PNG compression was not an option.

Answer (score 3):

While the solution of turning off Compress PNG images does work, it is not a good solution as it then no longer compresses PNG images. While not the most useful feature ever, it is standard and does obfuscate your images in your ipa which is usually a good thing.

This issue started with 10.7.3, today. No real solution has yet been put forward (other than to build your submissions with 10.7.2 instead.)

Comment: The Application Loader solution is the solution. Don't turn Compress PNG Images off.

Answer (score 1):

Check if your icon file is placed in the root project folder. The icon file should not be in any sub folder of your project folder. So if it is the case with you, just copy it to the root folder of your project and add to the project again.

Happy coding!

Comment: thanks for helping. actually i never put any icons, launch images in sub folder. i do try delete the app icon and add to the project again like you suggested (the icons is already placed in the root project folder). but still no luck..

Comment: Have you dragged and dropped your icon files on App Icons section in your Summray tab in Target settings?

Answer (score 1):

Download and Install the new application loader.

```
Quit Xcode. 
Restart Xcode.
Clean all Targets.
```

Try to submit!! :)

I've solved the issue!
NOTE: You must have only a copy of the Application Loader on you Mac. In you install thisIf you have a copy in `/Developer/Applications/Utilities`, and another version in `/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Applications`, you may run into problems. Pay Attention!!

Answer (score 0):

If you are using MAC OS version 10.7.3 and iTune version less than 10.6.Then while archiving you will face this issue.

So don't worry.Please update your iTune store to latest version(i.e 10.6).It will work perfectly fine.

Answer (score 0):

I tried 2 answers here and none seemed to solve my problem. After digging into some more detail I figured, the issue is in **AppName**-Info.plist

```
Project > Supporting Files > AppName-Info.plist
```

If you see closely, you will find the icons list is something like...

[image]

What I changed it to solve this...

[image]

Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and so tried to upload it via Application Loader (version 2.4.1) which still gave me the error. So I tried downloading latest version but could not install since it required MacOS 10.7 minimum. So I used version 2.5.1 which has the bug fixed and runs with MacOS 10.6.8

Link to v2.5.1
[ApplicationLoader_2.5.1.dmg](https://itunesconnect.apple.com/apploader/ApplicationLoader_2.5.1.dmg)