# iOS icon breaks app validation

Tags: ios, xcode, ipad

I have an iPad app that I submitted to Apple successfully using my personal Apple Developer account. However, when I switched code signing certificates, everything compiles and validates except the icon itself. Here is the error I get when I try to Archive the app.

```
iPad: Icon-72.png: icon dimensions (0 x 0) don't meet the size requirements.  The icon file must be 72x72 pixels, in .png format (-19014)
Unable to validate your application. - (null)
```

The icon is definitely a 72x72 PNG and this validates perfectly with my personal account.

Any ideas as to what might be causing this?

Thanks!

Comment: Is it possible to just delete the offending icon on disk and `svn update` or `git pull` to re-retrieve it and give it another go?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This has been discussed a lot today on the Apple Developer forums. I suspect it has to do with the recent Mac OS X Lion update and Xcode compatibility. I had this issue with the Icon.png file and the solution for me was to download Application Loader from iTunes Connect and use that to submit the application update.

So, I'd suggest bypassing Xcode's Orgranizer's validation and try to use Application Loader instead.

Comment: Thanks Moshe, indeed I could've looked a little deeper. Here's another stackoverflow thread with more info: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9108500/warning-ipad-icon-72-png-icon-dimensions-0-x-0

Answer (score 0):

This might help someone out there:
I eventually come across [this answer](http://iphonedevsdk.com/forum/iphone-sdk-development/47388-how-do-you-add-multiple-sized-icons-to-your-ipadiphone-universal-binary.html):

Apparently you need to add a row to your plist file if you want to deploy to both ipad and iphone.