# How to remove the warning that says "icon dimensions (0 x 0) don't meet the size requirements."?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, app-store

When i try to archive i am get a warning message saying "your Icon.png is not having the size of 57X57. But my image(Icon.png) is exactly 57X57.

The warning message displayed while archiving is as follows

> warning: iPhone/iPod Touch: Icon.png: icon dimensions (0 x 0) don't meet the size requirements.  The icon file must be 57x57 pixels, in .png format (-19014)
>   Unable to validate your application. - (null)
>    iPhone/iPod Touch: Icon.png: icon dimensions (0 x 0) don't meet the size requirements.  The icon file must be 57x57 pixels, in .png format (-19014)

Can anyone tell me how to remove this warning. Because with this warning i am unable to upload in app store

Comment: Are you on the latest Xcode version? This is a bug that was fixed by Apple recently.

Comment: Check the case of your icon filename is correct. Ensure that you have added it to your project correctly.

Comment: possible duplicate of [warning: iPad: Icon-72.png: icon dimensions (0 x 0)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9108500/warning-ipad-icon-72-png-icon-dimensions-0-x-0)

Comment: Many dupes: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9108500/warning-ipad-icon-72-png-icon-dimensions-0-x-0 http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9174514/app-submission-failed-due-to-icon-dimensions-0-x-0 http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9108500/warning-ipad-icon-72-png-icon-dimensions-0-x-0

Answer (score 5):

Had this same problem. Select your icon file and then change the file type (on the properties bar on the right) to "icon".

Answer (score 1):

An extract from the post [here](https://devforums.apple.com/thread/140067?tstart=0) which helped me take care of the problem:

> In your project settings, goto Build Settings > Packaging > Compress PNG files and make sure it's No / Unchecked.

Once you do this, just build and the warning should go away. Hope this helps!!

Answer (score 0):

Install [ApplicationLoader_2.5.1.dmg](https://itunesconnect.apple.com/apploader/ApplicationLoader_2.5.1.dmg) take a look at this [App submission failed due to icon dimensions (0 x 0)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9174514/app-submission-failed-due-to-icon-dimensions-0-x-0)

Answer (score 0):

right click the .png file and change the file type to image.ico